# How to cancel StreamBuilder's assigned stream on navigating to different screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform

Code:

```dart
final ref = Firestore.instance.document('some/path');

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  Stream _stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _stream = ref.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      // <--------------------------------------------------------------- line 1
      return snapshot.data;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2())),
              child: Text("Navigate"),
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => ref.updateData({'key': "value"}), // <------ line 2
        child: Text('Update data'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code is reproducible, no compile time error. Let me give you an overview.

There are 2 screen `Screen1` and `Screen2`. On first screen, I have set up a `StreamBuilder` which listens for value provided using `_stream`. So far so good.

But when I navigate to `Screen2` (see `line 2`), and update the server from it, the `Screen1` snapshot gets built again (see `line 1`). How can I cancel that `Stream` so that I don't have to be worry about when `Screen1` isn't in view?

Comment: check where [_unsubscribe()](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L154) method is called

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look thanks @pskink as usual